# I didnt see Allprojects repositories

Tags: firebase, android-studio

Firebase is not connecting and its show an error like Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.

some people say to remove the jcenter()..But in my app gradle i didnt see any all projects repository
This is my application built.gradle...

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}`
```

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem while adding "maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }" 
I solved the issue by adding it to *settings.gradle* file as below,

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem when trying to add a repository for "maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }" with gradle 7.0.2.

When I add the allprojects block: -

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

I get the following error.

> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'PetShop List'.
>
> Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'Google' was added by build file 'build.gradle'

The reason is due to the dependencyResolutionManagement block in **settings.gradle**.

To resolve it, simply go to  "settings.gradle" file comment off the whole block for 'dependencyResolutionManagement'.

Then reSync your project and it should work.

1. **Solution1**

[image]

2. **Solution2**

[image]

change like this in **settings.gradle**

```
import org.gradle.api.initialization.resolve.RepositoriesMode

dependencyResolutionManagement {

    repositories {
        google()
//    notice here -------------------------
        repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
        //    notice here -------------------------
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}
rootProject.name = "My Application"
include ':app'
```

Comment: when i comment this i  got an error like ..Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
   build-tools;30.0.2 Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2
To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

Comment: i found the answer i didnt install android sdktool which in setting.now i connected to firebase Thank you

Comment: Had to use solution two or I had a bunch of warnings

Answer (score 5):

Go to **`setting.gradle`** file. Then add `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` this line.

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]